# Better exposed filters override -any- only working on one filter at a time

Tags: views

I have a view on a Drupal 7 site which brings in all content from 3 content types, which all have 3 different entity reference fields attached to them in order to relate them to specific areas of the site. On the view, I need to beable to filter by the 3 content types, which i have done by creating a filter on type with the 3 options. For the 3 enitity reference fields I also need to be able to filter on all the references but also have an "Any" option to enable it to show all. Due to the design of the website I need the "Any" option to have a friendly title rather than any, which I have implementing using Better Exposed Filters. For some reason the Override any feature of BEF will only override 1 field. And completely ignores the other 2.

[image: Filters]

It is working on the final filter. If i remove this filter it will work on another one, but never more than one at a time. Is there a setting I'm missing or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed and patched, it hasn't been added to a release though
https://www.drupal.org/node/2260691

Answer (score 2):

I tried this kind of configuration with more then one exposed filter, yes its only overriding label for last exposed filter. May be a bug, Why not simply modify **-Any-** option label with `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'YOUR_VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME') {
    $form['FIRST_EXPOSED_FILTER_']['#options']['All'] = t('-NEW ANY LABEL');
    $form['SECOND_EXPOSED_FILTER_']['#options']['All'] = t('-NEW ANY LABEL');
    // and so on.        
  }
}
```

Comment: I used a JavaScript solution in the end.

Comment: @SeanLang: Which javascript solution? Can you please post here?

Comment: Added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1537074) and there is a patch that resolves the issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2293401).

Comment: I looked at this issue and it is actually different from what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @SeanLang you need to scroll down a bit to https://www.drupal.org/node/1537074#comment-8175329 to see the followup issues but the original feature request :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the temporary JavaScript solution I applied which takes the first child of the select list and changes its HTML.

```
$('.form-item-field-client-target-id select option:first-child').html('Who we work with');
$('.form-item-field-services-target-id select option:first-child').html('Services');
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic JS solution:

```
$('#SELECT-ID option[value="All"]').text('Whatever you want');
```

This will ensure that only the '- Any -' option will get changed and works on a case-by-case basis when you want to use a label in place of the '- Any -' text.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You referenced some other solution here. Please remember that other posts may get deleted. Make sure your answer will still make sense if this happens. Especially: be sure to include all explanations of **why** and **how** this answers the question.